# Soft lockup (freeze) on RPI 3 B and 64bit Ubuntu

Tags: kernel, 20.04, 19.04, freeze, lockup

I am running Ubuntu 64bit on my Raspberry Pi 3 B. There are several services running on that RPI but average system load is low.

However, after some days, I get a "soft lockup". The RPI is not responsive anymore. Both, the red and green LED are permanently on.

When I got the RPI connected to a monitor before the lockup, I got messages like:

```
rcu: INFO: rcu_sched deteced stalls on CPUs/task
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 22s!
```

[image: soft lockup messages]

---

*Common questions / trouble shooting*

**What Ubuntu Version am I using?** I tried 19.10 and 20.04 - the problem exists on both but seems to be worse on 20.04

**What about the soft lockup kernel panic setting?** Changing `/proc/sys/kernel/softlockup_panic` from 0 to 1 did not help - system still hangs and does not reboot.

**Why do I use 64bit?** Because a software package I use is only available in 64bit.

**What about the power supply?** I made sure to use an original RPI power supply (2.5 A).

**What about Rasbian OS?** When running the same setup using Rasbian 64bit, I did not experience this soft lockups. But 64bit support for Rasbian OS is still beta, and I might have other problems instead.

---

*Therefore my question:*

Is this known issue? a kernel bug? what to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just switched to Rasbian OS (Debian 10). All raspberry pi's are runnung stable for more than a month now.